# How can I force my functions to call in order?

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, behaviorsubject

**Summary:** I have a chart component, a filter menu component, and a service that filters and sets a BehaviorSubject. I want my service to initially make an http call to get data, my filter menu to pass filter dates to the service to filter the data, and finally my chart component to subscribe to the BehaviorSubject so it can display the filtered data.

**Filter Menu Component:**

```
export class FilterMenuComponent {
startDate: string;
endDate: stirng;

constructor(private service: FilterService) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.service.setData();
    this.setDates();
}

setDates() {
    //grabs dates from ui
    this.service.filterData(startDate, endDate);
}
```

**Filter Service:**

```
export class FilterService {
filteredDataBS: BehaviorSubject<Data>;
data: Data;

constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }

setData() {
    //http call to get initial data
    this._http.get().subscribe(data => {
        this.data = data;    
    });
}

filterData(startDate: string, endDate: string) {
    this.data = this.data.filter(xxxxxxxxxxxxxx); 
    this.filteredDataBS.next(data);
}
```

**Chart Component:**

```
export class ChartComponent {
data: Data;

constructor(private service: FilterService) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.service.filteredDataBS.subscribe(data => {
        this.data = data;
    });
}
```

**The problem:** Since the http call to set the intial data can take quite awhile, the `FilterMenuComponent` is already going ahead and calling to filter the data. I then get errors when calling `.filter on undefined`. I need the FilterMenuComponent to wait and call `this.service.filterData()` until AFTER the **FilterService** has gotten its initial data back from the http call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to return an observable from your function `setData` to detect when to filter the data. Here is how you can do it :

```
setData() {
  // Return an Observable to detect when data has
  // been received
  return new Obervable(observer => {
    //http call to get initial data
    this._http.get().subscribe(data => {
      this.data = data;
      observer.next();
    });
  });
}
```

Then subscribed to the observable in your FilterMenuComponent :

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.service.setData().subscribe(() => {
    this.setDates();
  });
}
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you! This allows me to not filter the data until its been returned, add conditionals to validate data before filtering so I don't error out, as well ensuring the http call is only made once

Answer (score 0):

Below is a solution

Filter Menu Component:

```
export class FilterMenuComponent {
startDate: string;
endDate: stirng;

constructor(private service: FilterService) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.service.setData();
    this.filteredDataBS.subscribe(result =>  this.setDates());
}

setDates() {
    //grabs dates from ui
    this.service.filterData(startDate, endDate);
}
```

Filter Service:

```
export class FilterService {
filteredDataBS: BehaviorSubject<Data>;
data: Data;

constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }

setData() {
    //http call to get initial data
    this._http.get().subscribe(data => {
        this.data = data;    
        this.filteredDataBS.next(data);
    });
}

filterData(startDate: string, endDate: string) {
    this.data = this.data.filter(xxxxxxxxxxxxxx); 
    this.filteredDataBS.next(data);
}
```

use filteredDataBS to indicate when the data of dates have been loaded and then use it via subscription

Answer (score 0):

Below is a solution

Filter Menu Component:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.service.setData();
    this.filteredDataBS.subscribe(result =>  this.setDates());
}
```

Filter Service:

```
setData() {
    //http call to get initial data
    this._http.get().subscribe(data => {
        this.data = data;    
        this.filteredDataBS.next(data);
    });
}
```

use filteredDataBS to indicate when the data of dates have been loaded and then use it via subscription

Answer (score 0):

Instead calling of `setDates()` in `ngOnInit` of `FilterMenuComponent`, you can call it in `_http.get()` callback:

```
setData(startDate, endDate) {
  //http call to get initial data
  this._http.get().subscribe(data => {
    this.data = data;
    this.filterData(startDate, endDate);
  });
}
```

but it requires passing `startDate` and `endDate`. You can also hold this variables in FilterService class as its properties.

If you wouldn't do this, just return finite Observable from `setData()` like other users suggest.

Comment: The only issue with this solution is that when dates are changed on the FilterMenuComponent, through a datepicker, I don't want it making the http call again. Sorry, I should have clarified in the post that the dates could be changed on the ui

Comment: You can call setDates() as a datepicker event handler :)